# How can I change the build action of a file when it is installed via NuGet

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget

### I have a project that is a package candidate and defines some custom assembly attributes

I want this project to deliver `.cs` files that are templates for using this attribute. However, I want the delivered file to produce a compile time error when it is installed to force consuming developers to make a conscious decision about the value that should be used in the attribute parameter.

The values encouraged (the type is simply string) are contained in a class containing public constants.

Lets say the values are thus:

```
public class Constants {
  public const string Common = nameof(Common);
  public const string Uncommon = nameof(Uncommon);
  public const string Assumed = nameof(Assumed);
}
```

I want to write the usage of my attribute to be delivered as such:

```
[assembly:MyAssembly(Constants.YourValue)]
```

How can I get the compiler to ignore this intentional compile error in the defining project and just treat it as content, but have the consuming project know that this file should be treated as `c# Compile` and should raise the compile time error?

If I change the `BuildAction` of the file to `content`, the compiler ignores it properly, but the consumer treats it as content too. If I keep the `BuildAction` as `c# Compile` then the defining project won't build, much less pack.

I'm currently using `dotnet pack` and would like to stay away from authoring a `.nuspec` explicitly.

I am also open to a more elegant method of delivering these "templates". I have considered authoring a `.targets` file and delivering that instead, but that doesn't give me the "prompt" for developers to change the value that nearly any c# dev would be familiar with.

Comment: > How can I get the compiler to ignore this intentional compile error in the defining project and just treat it as content

> but have the consuming project know that this file should be treated as c# Compile and should raise the compile time error?

I am trying to understand the difference between the 2. One is an action, the other one is a state. The project itself is all about building. 

Can you please elaborate a bit on that?

Comment: (as in my question) If I change the BuildAction property of the file to "content" in the defining proj, the compiler doesn't raise an error for `Constants.YourValue` when building the defining proj (this is what I want). However, installing the package in the consumer also does not raise an error for `Constants.YourValue` when building the consumer proj because the BuildAction remains as "content" (this is NOT what I want).

Comment: Ahh, so the problem is on the building side. You want to specify the build action to Build for the package generated by the project, but you don't want the project in question to build it? 

Are you packing using the csproj? 
Is this the answer for you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#targetsfortfmspecificcontentinpackage

Comment: This is interesting, and may be just want I'm looking for. I'll try it out and see what happens in the consumer after specifying the `c# Compile` build action in the target. If you want to write up a more detailed answer, I'll mark it if my test provides the desired result.